# Magento site is not working with www in url

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a website which is working fine. There is a footer link to access media files. It was working fine But i changed the media files to new files, but with the same name. Then this page is not working when the url loads with www. with www old content is loading in the page. Without www new content is loading in the page.

Since i did not do any other files changes i am confuse what is wrong here.

Can anyone please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the url ? this may happen due to caching engine and you have inappropriate url redirection. The site should only render with www or without www.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Magento Cache , you must be using CDN as well which in configured with www.yoururl.com do clear the CDN cache as well